# UITableView swipe to edit

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, segue, swipe

I have two uitableviewcontroller , one is lists table and the other is editing table.
I use accessory action to edit item. it works fine.

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if  segue.identifier == "EditItem" {
        let controller = segue.destination as! ItemDetailViewController
        controller.delegate = self
        if let indexPath = tableView.indexPath(for: sender as! UITableViewCell) {

            controller.itemToEdit = items[indexPath.row]
        }
    }
}
```

now I add swipe function to  edit item

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, trailingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UISwipeActionsConfiguration? {

    let edit = UIContextualAction(style: .normal, title: "Edit") { action, view, completion in
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "EditItem", sender: self)

        completion(true)
    }

    let delete = UIContextualAction(style: .destructive, title: "Delete") { [weak self] action, view, completion in
        self?.items.remove(at: indexPath.row)
        tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: UITableView.RowAnimation.automatic)
        self?.saveChannelListItems()
        completion(true)
    }

    edit.backgroundColor = .purple
    edit.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "edit")
    delete.backgroundColor = .red
    delete.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "delete")


    return UISwipeActionsConfiguration(actions: [delete, edit])
}
```

then I have errors.

> Could not cast value of type 'abc.ListController' (0x1089b1398) to 'UITableViewCell' (0x1150f18e0).

how can I swipe to edit items?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you send `self` which is the vc in `sender` parameter

```
self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "EditItem", sender: self)
```

and force unwrap it to the cell which is the problem

```
if let indexPath = tableView.indexPath(for: sender as! UITableViewCell) {
```

---

Instead you can do

```
self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "EditItem", sender:items[indexPath.row])
```

with

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if  segue.identifier == "EditItem" {
         let controller = segue.destination as! ItemDetailViewController
         controller.delegate = self 
         controller.itemToEdit = sender as! ItemType // where ItemType is the type of the array elements 
        }
    }
}
```